# Change the result of mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Can I modify the result that I have received from mysql_query than reset the pointer with mysql_data_seek($result, 0) and process the output like from normal query

Dummy example:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $row[$fieldName] = $this->someFunction($row['id']);
}
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

In current example it doesn't works. The changing that I made to $row doesn't save. Is it possible to realise such idea, about changing $result?

Comment: Not sure if this works in principle, but to use $row[$fieldName] like this, wouldn't you have to use mysq_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: as hinted in the comment below, it's not clear whether you want the content of $row to be changed, or whether you want the changed values to be written back to the database - can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a whapper around $result to make such things. But i advice you to change your minnd about why do you need it. There should be better way

Comment: It will be great if you will describe how to do this wrapper.
In other way I need to change "tons" of others code :(

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible if you'd used e.g. [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo). But with the "old" [mysql extension](http://docs.php.net/mysql)? No, not the way you most likely want it to work.